# javascript how to select elements and style it

Tags: javascript, css, parsing, select, styles

May I know how to build a CSS style parser/evaluator in JavaScript for below:

```
.book { width: calc(200px + 400px); }
.book h1 { font-size: 10em; }
div.book { color: blue; }
.book.green { background: green; }
.book[name="hello"] { color: pink; }
.book[data-name="hi"], .other-book { color: red; }
.book > a { text-decoration: none; }
.book a:nth-child(2) { color: purple; }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does getElementsByClassName return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-does-getelementsbyclassname-return)

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName('box')` actually returns a collection. You should specify a specific index inside square brackets like this

```
document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0].style.width = '100px';
```

This has to do with the difference between `classes` and `ids`. There can be multiple elements with the same class name, but ids are unique. The same formula as

```
document.getElementById
```

does not work with classes, because of the difference I mentioned above.

Although, this is best done through css.

Comment: for .box > a , how do i select

Comment: i would like to do CSS style parser/evaluator in JavaScript.

Comment: Why? CSS is used for styling and JavaScript for behavior.